# Hide a disk E: in "Computer" view of Windows Explorer, but still have it mounted as E:

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-explorer, ntfs

I know how to hide a volume with DISKMGMT.MSC (Right click, *Change Drive Letter and Paths*, and remove the drive letter),

[image]

but here I want something a little bit different:

I would like to **still have the disk mounted** as E: (thus we can launch a program there, we can access it via cmd.exe, symlinks to E:\mydirectory\ will still work, etc.)  but **just not see it in the Computer Explorer view:**

[image]

How to do this?

(I'm admin, and there is only 1 user account).

---

Note: [Using gpedit.msc](https://superuser.com/a/238275/221041) doesn't work, no option to remove E: only appears in the list:

[image]

Comment: You can hide them easily through either a group policy from the domain or using gpedit.msc as a local group policy. It is in essence the same as the answer with registry, except, its error prone and has a GUI. So its far easier to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide drives in Windows Explorer using a user-specific registry setting. Create a new registry entry using `regedit` in the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

called `NoDrives`, type DWORD, and set it to a decimal value of 16 (which stands for `E:`; see list below). If you want to hide multiple drives, you just add the values. For example, to hide both D and E, add 8+16 and enter 24 as decimal value in `regedit`.

You will probably need to log off your user and login again for the changes
to become effective. And: the drive is just hidden – it still can be accessed. 
By command line of course, but also using Explorer if someone manually types in `E:\` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the address bar.

```
A   1
B   2
C   4
D   8
E   16
F   32
G   64
H   128
I   256
J   512
K   1024
L   2048
M   4096
N   8192
O   16384
P   32768
Q   65536
R   131072
S   262144
T   524288
U   1048576
V   2097152
W   4194304
X   8388608
Y   16777216
Z   33554432
```